# Overriding Hosted Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, overriding

I'm relatively new to javascript.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to override a javascript function from a hosted JS.

**Background:**

We won't be able to accept Amex card payment (Bank Issue). However, our embedded donation form still detects Amex cards when the card number is inserted.

Using Chrome, found this function, that I'm guessing is used to auto-detect card types. /

```html
function a(n) {
    var m = /^4/,
        i = /(^5[1-5])|^(222[1-8][0-9]{2}|2229[0-8][0-9]|22299[0-9]|22[3-9][0-9]{3}|2[3-6][0-9]{4}|27[01][0-9]{3}|2720[0-8][0-9]|27209[0-9])/,
        o = /^3[47]/,
        l = /^6(?:011|5|4[4-9]|22(?:1(?:2[6-9]|[3-9])|[2-8]|9(?:[01]|2[0-5])))/,
        h = /^(?:5[0678]|6304|6390|67)/,
        j = /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]/,
        k = /^(4026|417500|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917)/;
    if (k.test(n)) {
        return "electron"
    } else {
        if (m.test(n)) {
            return "visa"
        } else {
            if (i.test(n)) {
                return "mastercard"
            } else {
                if (o.test(n)) {
                    return "amex"
                } else {
                    if (l.test(n)) {
                        return "discover"
                    } else {
                        if (h.test(n)) {
                            return "maestro"
                        } else {
                            if (j.test(n)) {
                                return "diners"
                            } else {
                                return "unknown"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will I be able to override the *"o=/^3[47]/"* to something else or remove it completely so Amex cards can't be detected, then insert in  inside HTML?

Comment: Detecting != accepting. Changing this piece of code hardly will suffice. You really should contact the service who provides the "embedded donation form" and ask them what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe a solution is to make your own if statement if amex is returned, so that you will set amex to unknown to.

```
var card = function a(n);
if(a === 'unknown' || a === 'amex'){
DoStuff();
}else{
DoRecognizedstuff();
}
```

This will help you solve the problem. Is this not what you want? You can also rewrite the function to this:

```js
function a(n) {
    var m = /^4/,
        i = /(^5[1-5])|^(222[1-8][0-9]{2}|2229[0-8][0-9]|22299[0-9]|22[3-9][0-9]{3}|2[3-6][0-9]{4}|27[01][0-9]{3}|2720[0-8][0-9]|27209[0-9])/,
        l = /^6(?:011|5|4[4-9]|22(?:1(?:2[6-9]|[3-9])|[2-8]|9(?:[01]|2[0-5])))/,
        h = /^(?:5[0678]|6304|6390|67)/,
        j = /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]/,
        k = /^(4026|417500|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917)/;
    if (k.test(n)) {
        return "electron"
    } else {
        if (m.test(n)) {
            return "visa"
        } else {
            if (i.test(n)) {
                return "mastercard"
            } else {
                 if (l.test(n)) {
                        return "discover"
                    } else {
                        if (h.test(n)) {
                            return "maestro"
                        } else {
                            if (j.test(n)) {
                                return "diners"
                            } else {
                                return "unknown"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will only be possible if you call this function yourself. If it is called by a callback or something from the hosted JS it will not work. If this is a standalone script, you can just host the JS as your own.

Comment: Yes, it is a callback from the hosted JS. However, you're saying by copying the code you created and placing it inside <script></script>, it'll work?

Comment: Also, here is the embed JS. Can something be made in here?  

window.bboxInit = function () {
           bbox.showForm('039de06f-b1e1-4704-ab40-ce5942a27a32');
       };
       (function () {
           var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
           e.src = 'https://bbox.blackbaudhosting.com/webforms/bbox-min.js';
           document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
       } ());

Comment: Hello, I don't know if it will work because I cannot load the webform. But what I suggest is that in the form you put on your website you do the check I made above. So that you will do the same for amex as unknown. If the form is loaded you can use javascript to check the value in the form. If the value is amex you can change the value to unknown. So the value will always be unknown when amex is put in